# Laravel - Tabla no muestra registro de horarios

Tags: mysql, validación, laravel-blade

Tengo una tabla de horarios de médicos en Laravel, pero ésta no me muestra los horarios para los nuevos médicos que aún no han sido registrados (su horario).

**Estos horarios no son traídos** desde la base de datos en una primera instancia. Ya que necesito primero registrar esos horarios en la base de datos, luego de eso al editar el horario si me muestra los horarios, como se verá en la imagen más adelante.

Esta imagen corresponde a un registro que tiene los horarios registrados en la base de datos. Lo pude registrar antes de hacer un cambio en el código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego, de hacer el cambio en el código me dejó de mostrar el registro que no extraigo desde la base de datos, porque primero necesito registrar. Lo hago todo en una misma vista, porque hacerlo por separado no podia controlar las duplicaciones de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver esta vacío y debería mostrarme una tabla que tengo, recuerden. En este punto no extraigo los horarios desde la base de datos, es después de registrar el horario.

Explico, debería estar todos los select box marcando las 09:00 AM. Pero en la imagen se ve vacío. Al extraer desde la base de datos algunos días dirán un horario distinto a **"09:00 AM"**, como lo muestra la 1era imagen. De eso se trata el problema y no logro entender muy bien por qué está vacío, entiendo que es porque no hay registros en la BD pero necesito que me muestre la tabla.

Ahora muestro el código, el cambio que hice entre un antes y después es una porción de código que incluye una validación en PHP que deja seleccionado en el select box el horario del usuario correspondiente desde la base de datos.

Solo dejo un fragmento de código donde tengo un *@foreach*, para que esto no sea muy largo y se mantenga el foco.

```
@foreach($horarios as $num_dias => $turno)                  

    <tr id="columnaHover">
      <th class="align-middle">{{$dias[$num_dias]}}</th>
        <td class="align-middle">                 
          <input type="checkbox" value="{{$num_dias}}" id="dias_medico" name="dias_medico[]" @if($turno->activo) checked @endif >
        </td>

        <td>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <select class="form-control" name="inicio_turno_dia[]" title="Hora Inicio">
                @for($i=9; $i<=11; $i++)
                  
                  @php
                    $selected = ($i.':00 AM' == $turno->inicio_turno_dia) || ($i.':30 AM' == $turno->inicio_turno_dia) ? 'selected' : '';
                  @endphp
                  <option value="{{ ($i<10 ? '0' : '') . $i }}:00" {{$selected}}>{{$i}}:00 AM</option>
                  <option value="{{ ($i<10 ? '0' : '') . $i }}:30" {{$selected}}>{{$i}}:30 AM</option>
                @endfor
                <option value=" ">Sin Horario</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>

        <td>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <select class="form-control" name="fin_turno_dia[]" title="Hora Fin">
                @for($i=9; $i<=11; $i++)
                
                  @php
                    $selected = ($i.':00 AM' == $turno->fin_turno_dia) || ($i.':30 AM' == $turno->fin_turno_dia) ? 'selected' : '';
                  @endphp
                  <option value="{{ ($i<10 ? '0' : '') . $i }}:00" {{$selected}}>{{$i}}:00 AM</option>
                  <option value="{{ ($i<10 ? '0' : '') . $i }}:30" {{$selected}}>{{$i}}:30 AM</option>
                @endfor
                <option value=" ">Sin Horario</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>

        <td>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <select class="form-control" name="inicio_turno_tarde[]" title="Hora Inicio Tarde">
              @for($i=2; $i<=7; $i++)
                @php
                  $selected = ($i.':00 PM' == $turno->inicio_turno_tarde) || ($i.':30 PM' == $turno->inicio_turno_tarde) || ($i.'  ' == $turno->fin_turno_tarde) ? 'selected' : '';
                @endphp
                <option value="{{$i+12}}:00" {{$selected}}>{{$i+12}}:00 PM</option>
                <option value="{{$i+12}}:30" {{$selected}}>{{$i+12}}:30 PM</option>
              @endfor
              <option value=" ">Sin Horario</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <select class="form-control" name="fin_turno_tarde[]" title="Hora Fin Tarde">
            @for($i=2; $i<=7; $i++)
              @php
                $selected = ($i.':00 PM' == $turno->fin_turno_tarde) || ($i.':30 PM' == $turno->fin_turno_tarde) ? 'selected' : '';
              @endphp
              <option value="{{$i+12}}:00" {{$selected}}>{{$i+12}}:00 PM</option>
              <option value="{{$i+12}}:30" {{$selected}}>{{$i+12}}:30 PM</option>
            @endfor
            <option value=" ">Sin Horario</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Para una mayor comprensión del código que marca el antes y después, dejo ahora un fragmento.

```
@php
    $selected = ($i.':00 PM' == $turno->fin_turno_tarde) || ($i.':30 PM' == $turno->fin_turno_tarde) ? 'selected' : '';
@endphp
```

Eso me funciona muy bien, muestra los registros que tengo en la base de datos de los horarios de los medicos, que tengo registrado.

Mencioné en un punto que traigo datos desde la BD y dejo ahora ese código. Aunque en realidad hago varias cosas en ese código, como por ejemplo usar CARBON para dar un formato a la hora. Pero lo dejo para poder entregar un mejor contexto al problema.

```
public function edit(Medicos $medicos){

    $datos = DB::table('medicos')
    ->join('especialidad','medicos.especialidad_id','=','especialidad.id_especialidad')
    ->selectRaw("medicos.id_doctor AS doctor_id, medicos.nombre AS doctor, medicos.apellidos AS surname, CONCAT(medicos.nombre,' ',medicos.apellidos) AS nombre_medico, rut, fecha_nacimiento, especialidad.nombre_especialidad AS especialidad, especialidad_id")
    ->where('medicos.id_doctor', '=' ,$medicos->id_doctor)->first();
    
    
    $dias = ['Lunes','Martes','Miercoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sabado','Domigo'];


    $horarios = Horarios::where('id_usuario',$medicos->id_doctor)->get();

    $horarios->map(function($horarios){

        $horarios->inicio_turno_dia = (new Carbon($horarios->inicio_turno_dia))->format('g:i A');
        $horarios->fin_turno_dia = (new Carbon($horarios->fin_turno_dia))->format('g:i A');

        $horarios->inicio_turno_tarde = (new Carbon($horarios->inicio_turno_tarde))->format('g:i A');
        $horarios->fin_turno_tarde = (new Carbon($horarios->fin_turno_tarde))->format('g:i A');

    });
  

    return view('forms.editar-horarios', compact('datos','medicos','dias','horarios'));
}
```

Ahora quiero explicar un punto, porque estoy seguro de que alguien se puede preguntar lo siguiente:

Por qué hago todo esto en una sola vista, porque intenté hacerlo separado, pero no logré controlar la duplicación de datos, yo ocupaba un "select box" con los nombres de los medicos (se guarda su ID) pero mi idea era que, al momento de registrar los horarios de los medicos, el "select box" que contenía los nombres de los medicos (su valor era sus respectivos ID) cada vez que se registraba a uno, luego su nombre (ya registrado) técnicamente "desaparecía" del listado.

Un ejemplo, si Roberto Perez es Pediatra, y el siguiente en el listado es Romina Flores Dentista, luego de registrar los días y el horario de Roberto Perez, el siguiente medico a registrar (en este ejemplo hay 2 solamente) debería ser Romina Flores, y el select box me debe mostrar solamente ese nombre y no los 2 además, si ya no quedaba ninguno más por registrar me debía decir la opción "no hay médicos disponibles". Esa era mi idea, pero no logré hacerlo bien tenía muchos errores investigaba siempre pero no me funcionaba, lo sencillo que me resultó **bien** fue eso en **una sola vista agregar y editar los horarios**. Ciertamente agregar se producía 1 sola vez, y ya no tenía problemas con las duplicaciones de datos.

Luego, a continuación:

**La primera imagen de todas formas tiene errores**, por un lado, está bien que me muestre los demás días que no están marcados (checkbox) con el horario marcado en 09:00 AM, pero esta vez estoy trayendo datos desde la BD y debería mostrarme la opción "Sin Horario".

En el momento de registrar el horario del médico está la alternativa de indicar al usuario cuando un médico no atiende en ciertos días, y por eso hay checkboxes que no están marcados.

El "select box" tiene una opción que dice **"Sin horario"** y su valor es un valor NULO. Ese valor **se guarda en la BD como NULL**.

Y luego tengo adicional a ese problema, el asunto que los demás médicos que aún no tienen horario no me muestra la tabla con los días y horarios en 09:00 AM, recordad que en ese punto es una tabla sencilla sin datos traídos desde la BD y debería mostrarse en vez de mostrar ese espacio vacío.

Comprendo que tiene que ver esa validación que hice *(@php - @endphp)* que lo que hace es ver si el registro está presente para realizar la validación de mostrar bien los horarios.

Pero no entiendo cómo puedo solucionarlo y me gustaría recibir ayuda, sugerencias, consejos y/o alguna explicación con código que me pueda ayudar. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

yo creo que tu problema esta en el foreach sobre $horarios en el inicio de la vista

segun tu controlador $horarios sale de la tabla de medicos

pero como dijiste . algunos medicos todavia no tienen horarios guardados en la tabla

entonces  $horarios esta vacio y tu foreach NO itera.

deberias ver en tu controlador que si $horarios esta vacio . lo rellenes CON las opciones de horarios que creas conveniente para que tu foreach del principio de la vista funcione.

podria ser asi

```
    if($horarios) {   //esto verifica si $horarios tiene registros

        //va tu codigo con el map

    } else {

       //rellenar horarios con las opciones que quieras que aparezcan

    }
```

espero te sirva
saludos

Comment: Mmmm lo hice, tuve que negar en ese if para que funcione, _@if(!$horarios){}_ y me muestre los horarios correctamente, tambien intenté invertir sin necesidad de negar con **!** y no funcionó ese intento. Tambien probe usar **@elseif()** y negar $horarios, pero tampoco funcionó. Necesito usar  **@foreach()** para que me muestre los 7 días de la semana con los horarios para guardar. Use lo mismo que tengo en mi pregunta, pero sin validaciones simplemente es un **@foreach** que muestra los 7 dias de la semana, pero no funciona con los otros médicos que no tienen horario, guardado en la BD

Answer (score 0):

Perdón M4uriXD quizá no me exprese correctamente. y eso llevo a que me malinterpretes.

El problema no se resuelve en la vista sino en el controlador.

Lo que necesita es que $horarios tenga algo dentro,  ya sea los horarios del medico o los horarios vacios.

Entonces podrías hacerlo de dos maneras a mi entender.

1. agregar en la tabla de horarios, horarios de un medico ficticio ,por ejemplo con id 1 . Entonces en tu código podrías hacer lo siguiente:

   ```
       $horarios = Horarios::where('id_usuario',$medicos->id_doctor)->get();

       if(!$horarios) {   
            //esto verifica si $horarios no tiene registros
            // entonces buscas esos horarios del medico ficticio con id 1

            $horarios = Horarios::where('id_usuario',1)->get();
        };
   ```
2. crear un objeto horarios con los datos que necesites

   ```
      $horarios = Horarios::where('id_usuario',$medicos->id_doctor)->get();

      if(!$horarios) {   
           //esto verifica si $horarios no tiene registros
           // entonces creas una matriz con los datos que necesitas

           $temporal = [['inicio_turno_dia' => "09:00" ,
                        'fin_turno_dia'   => "12:00",   
                        'inicio_turno_tarde'   => "15:00",  
                        'fin_turno_tarde'   => "20:00",    

                        }};

           //convierte a un objeto
           $horarios = (object) $temporal;
       };
   ```

Por supuesto, estos son solo ejemplos, queda a tu discreción que hacer.

Espero te ayude. saludos